# Using template template parameter on function call

Tags: c++, templates, factory-pattern, command-pattern

Actually, all the answers are nice, and informative but they don't solve my particular problem. I don't think that's the fault of the very helpful people who replied but instead, I badly phrased my question. Therefore I decided to post a completely new question with more relevant code examples here : [Mixing Command pattern, Factory pattern and templates all together ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972818/mixing-command-pattern-factory-pattern-and-templates-all-together/11972914#11972914) . If anyone cares to look ...

Now the original question :

I dont think it's possible to do what I want but I ask, just in case....

I have a familly of template classes I'd like to create through a factory. 
The reason why I use a factory is because the factory has some data members which are used for initializing every class created through that factory.

For example, let's consider this class :

```
class DoSomething : public UndoableCommand< int, float >
```

I tried to create a command factory, so it can create classes like the one above, and take care of their initialization, lifetime etc ...

In my (non-template) CommandFactory, I defined the following method :

```
template < template <typename P1, typename P2, typename P3, typename P4> class CommandType> 
void createCommand(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
{
UndoableCommand* cmdPtr;
cmdPtr=new CommandType(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4);
//...
}
```

However, this doesn't compile. The line "void operator()(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)" produces the following error :

> error C2065: 'P1' : undeclared identifier

Because classes like "DoSomething" have only one declaration (DoSomething will always use  < int, float >), I thought that I could use template argument deduction, and end up with a syntax like :

```
myCommandFactory.createCommand<DoSomething>( 1 /*int*/, 1.0f /*float*/);
```

**Is it possible at all ? If so, what's the appropriate syntax ?**

I guess I could always define my factory method like :

```
template <class CommandType, typename P1, typename P2, typename P3, typename P4> 
void createCommand(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4)
{
UndoableCommand* cmdPtr;
cmdPtr=new CommandType(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3, P4 p4);
//...
}
```

and then call

```
myCommandFactory.createCommand<DoSomething, int, float>( 1 /*int*/, 1.0f /*float*/);
```

but that is redundant and not very elegant...

Comment: There is no such thing as a `template class`, there are only `class templates`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
struct UndoableCommand { };

template <
    template <typename P1, typename P2> class CommandType,
    typename P1a, typename P2a
         >
void createCommand(P1a p1, P2a p2)
{
    UndoableCommand *cmdPtr = new CommandType<P1a,P2a>(p1, p2);
}

template <typename P1, typename P2> class MyCommand : public UndoableCommand
{
public:
    MyCommand(P1, P2) { }
};

int main()
{
   createCommand<MyCommand>(1, 2.0);
}
```

It compiles at: http://ideone.com/tEWR5

Comment: I would have the template-template argument be first, so that it could be used as `createCommand<CommandType>(args)`, without having to specify the types of the arguments.

Comment: Wow you guys ghave a deeper undertsanding of templates than me ! Kirill, your code seems to work . I didn't try to actually call the create method yet because I have other errors, but at least it compiles. Dave, would you mind developping your answer please ?

Comment: Ok regarding the update, createCommand is now a free function. I already had that working before, but now I need it to be a member function ( The reason why I use a factory is because the factory has some data members which are used for initializing every class created through that factory.). But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, defined like here

```
class DoSomething : public UndoableCommand< int, float >
```

`DoSomething` is a type, not a template, so you cannot use it with such a function.

Lets consider, you defined `DoSomething` like

```
template <typename T, typename V>
struct DoSmth: public UndoableCommand {
    DoSmth(T, V){}
};
```

Then, I noted, that your function has 4 params, but your `DoSomething` has only 2. If you really want use variable count of parameters, you should use variadic templates.

So, your function should look like that:

```
struct Factory
{
    template < template <typename...> class CommandType, typename... T> 
    void createCommand(T... args)
    {
        UndoableCommand* cmdPtr = new CommandType<T...>(args...);
    }
};
```

And you can use it the following way:

```
int main()
{
    Factory f;
    f.createCommand<DoSmth>(1, false);
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Your example is what I really do  in the code, I just oversimplified it and made it wrong. My bad. However, I'd really like to have a member function instead of a free function. There's no way, is it ?

Comment: @Dinaiz, You want make `createCommand` member function? just do it! there is no any problems, except it should be _defined_ (in opposit to _declared_) in header file (not in `cpp` file)

Comment: @Dinaiz, yes, because of variadic templates. If you get rid of them, it will work with c++98, but then you will have to define different overloads for every parameters count, you use.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, why not to make it free function then? `Dinaiz` wanted to make it member function, he didn't mention, that is should be static. I gave an example.

Comment: anyways correct the typo in your answer : `template <typename T, typename V>: public UndoableCommand` I had edited it but some reviewer felt my edit is wrong so reversed the edit 0o